# Upgrade Mountain Lion to Mavericks, with DMG file obtained from unofficial source?

Tags: macos

I am trying to update from Mountain Lion to Mavericks using a DMG installer that I obtained over BitTorrent.  I don't want to download it via the official App Store as I don't have good enough Internet connectivity to download the 5 GB file.

How do I install from this DMG file?  I tried double clicking the DMG file, double clicking OS X Install Mavericks.app, then clicking install; I am shown the software license agreement, and I accepted it, but nothing happens after accepting the software license agreement.

Comment: Please do [research](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions. You don't need an external hard drive to install Mavericks. Just doubeclick the .dmg, then click on "Install OS X". That's it.

Comment: hi napcae, i have already done that, upto agreeing apple's software agreement is ok, but nothing happens when i click install button after that

Comment: You'll want to show details about the file you run and perhaps document the steps you are taking to narrow down how your issue is different than how to make an installer as opposed how to use the installer you acquired from an alternate source than Apple. You might just have an old / corrupt / modified installer.

Comment: i have acquired file from torrent where it has been mentioned that it is from App Store and untouched. My steps:
1) double click dmg file
2) double click osx install mavericks.app
3) click install

Comment: @lg_shant I would assume that the torrented file is not correct

Comment: i guess so, thanks @bmike and Mark .. i am not being offensive, but for those who downgraded question, sitting in underdeveloped country with inconsistent and poor internet connectivity, you will know why i am asking these..

Comment: Your question title says "offline" -- are you disconnected from the internet when you're running the upgrade tool? If not, it may be doing a slow check to ensure the contents of the installer are valid and that it's the latest version of the OS -- try disconnecting from the internet in this case. If you ARE disconnected from the internet the hangup may be caused by the installer trying to contact Apple -- try connecting to the internet in this case and running the installer again.

Comment: sorry for my language, as it is not expressed clearly , here by offline means , it is not the case that i am disconnected from internet rather i am not installing from App Store directly.. i guess file is corrupted..

Comment: I've been trying for days to download this file and I just wish Apple would provide a direct download link. This file is way too big and their App Store is rubbish at handling it. Why leave that to non-official (and potentially unsafe) torrents when they could do it themselves. It's obvious there's a demand for this kind of link, not everybody is in the US with a fast and reliable internet connection.